# How to modify the default variable type defined by "all_categorical()" in "gtsummary"? when mean of ordinal variable were wanted?

Tags: gtsummary

The variable "Var2" has been set as categorical variable by default, while the mean(sd) were needed sometimes. So I am interested in how to modified this.

```
data_table_1 = 
  data %>% 
  dplyr::select(group, var1, var2)


data_table_1 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = group, missing = "no",
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}",
                               all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
              digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(2, 2))) %>%
  add_p(test = list(all_continuous() ~ "pttest2", all_categorical() ~ "pttest2"),
        pvalue_fun = function(x) sprintf(x, fmt='%#.3f'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `tbl_summary()` does its best to guess the type of summary that best suits the data...but this is not always how you'd like to summarize your data.  To update the default summary type, use the `type=` argument.  In this case you'd want to include `type = list(Var2 ~ "continuous")` to summarize the data continuously.

Hope this helps!